# How to test jquery .slideDown() and slideUp() by code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing

I use the jQuery to hide and show a div.

```
function bindIconClick() {
    $('span.scroIcon').click(function(event) {
        var eventIcon = $(event.target);
        var contentPanel = eventIcon.parents('.panelTitle').next();
        if (contentPanel.is(':hidden')) {
            contentPanel.slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            contentPanel.slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
}
```

I want to test the function, I can use the trigger() to simulate the click event, but I don't know how to test the slideDown() and slideUp() effect.

I want to test the function bindIconClick ,means if I use the trigger() function simulate the click event, I want know does the contentPanel hide or show.

I want to test the full function bindIconClick ,  not the part of it. I want to test the full function is correct!

In fact , I want to test the effetc that when the span be clicked, will contentPanel hide or show ?

Comment: Use `contentPanel.slideToggle('slow')` instead of `if` -> up else down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *[**slideToggle**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)* function instead of if and else

```
function bindIconClick() {
    $('span.scroIcon').click(function(event) {
        var eventIcon = $(event.target);
        var contentPanel = eventIcon.parents('.panelTitle').next();
        contentPanel.slideToggle('slow');
    });
}
```

Comment: I want know how to test the function bindIconClick.

Comment: Can you explain bit what you want? Or you simply call your function? Or You want to design the test cases for that